# Is there a way to send custom parameters along with a redirect action using twilio autopilot?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I would like to send custom parameters along with my redirect request in addition to the ones provided by twilio (https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/autopilot-request) - I wasn't able to find anything in the docs. Does anyone know how I could achieve this? Or is passing through the URL the only way?

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "redirect": {
                "method": "POST",
                "uri": "https://my-node-app/params/1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL query parameters as you stated.

`https://my-node-app/params/1?param1=x&param2=y&param3=z`